# Microsoft Outlook ignoring WPAD mechanism

Tags: microsoft-outlook, proxy, office365, wpad

we have many users connecting to Microsoft's servers when using Office 365.
In order to get around our proxy servers, we have implemented a WPAD system which hosts a list of sites for which the proxy server should be used and for which no proxy server is to be used.
The list of sites that have to be contacted directly is directly from Microsoft and is up to date.
(https://endpoints.office.com/endpoints/worldwide)
Most of our users do not see any issues and the mechanism is working perfectly fine.

But for some of our users, the requests to the servers are reaching the proxy server and are blocked then - even though they are listed in the WPAD file to go DIRECT.
When using tools to check the function of the WPAD, everything seems to be fine and the URL in question is directed *DIRECT* and not to a proxy server.

It seems that Outlook sometimes (?) ignores the WPAD file and sends requests to the proxy server although the requests should be sent directly according to the WPAD file.

The WPAD URL is distributed both via DHCP and DNS and the DNS server is configured to allow queries to "wpad".

Any idea why those URLs are sometimes found in the proxy logs and why some of our users cannot start Outlook even thoud the respective URLs are properly configured in the WPAD file?

Best regards
Tom

Comment: Know few about WPAD, found a similar issue for your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef29b9ff-55ac-4d4e-a03d-66dddd122bde/outlook-and-wpad-proxy-configuration?forum=outlook

Comment: How is everything going now?

Comment: Things seem to have improved. I think this was definitely an issue, but we still see strange behaviour. We need to debug that further, though... If you write your comment as an answer, I'll mark that as the solution.

Comment: Sure, willing to do that~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a similar issue for your reference:

[outlook and wpad proxy configuration](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef29b9ff-55ac-4d4e-a03d-66dddd122bde/outlook-and-wpad-proxy-configuration?forum=outlook)

Hope this could give you some inspiration.